# Construct: VarInt integer encoding

Tags: python, parsing, integer

This code is part of the [Construct](https://github.com/construct/construct) library. Docstrings explain what the code is supposed to do.

```
@singleton
class VarInt(Construct):
    r"""
    Varint encoded integer. Each 7 bits of the number are encoded in one byte in the stream, having leftmost bit not set when byte is terminal.

    Scheme defined at Google's site:
    https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding
    https://techoverflow.net/blog/2013/01/25/efficiently-encoding-variable-length-integers-in-cc/

    Example::

        >>> VarInt.build(16)
        b'\x10'
        >>> VarInt.parse(_)
        16
        >>> VarInt.build(2**100)
        b'\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80\x04'
        >>> VarInt.parse(_)
        1267650600228229401496703205376
    """
    def _parse(self, stream, context, path):
        acc = []
        while True:
            b = byte2int(_read_stream(stream, 1))
            acc.append(b & 0b01111111)
            if not b & 0b10000000:
                break
        num = 0
        for b in reversed(acc):
            num = (num << 7) | b
        return num
    def _build(self, obj, stream, context, path):
        if obj < 0:
            raise ValueError("varint cannot build from negative number")
        while obj > 0b01111111:
            _write_stream(stream, 1, int2byte(0b10000000 | (obj & 0b01111111)))
            obj >>= 7
        _write_stream(stream, 1, int2byte(obj))
```

some of the code refers to:
https://github.com/construct/construct/blob/master/construct/lib/py3compat.py

Comment: Please could you write a summary of what this code is meant to do

Comment: @TolaniJaiye-Tikolo The title says it all. `varint` is a well-known protocol.

Comment: For the sake of others that are reviewing your code, you should explain in detail what your code does and what you want from the review i.e performance. Please visit the help guide on [ask] . I would also assume this code is in python , this should have been added in your tags as well.

Comment: I would take any kind of review, performance or correctness or otherwise. And VarInt is an an encoding, not a protocol, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A class with no state is a good indication that the class is not needed. Free functions will do just fine.
- `context` and `path` play no role neither in parsing nor in building. Consider not to pass them.
- I don't see a need for two passes in `parse`. Consider

  ```
  def _parse(stream):
      num = 0
      while True:
          b = byte2int(_read_stream(stream, 1))
          num << 7
          num |= b & 0b01111111
          if not b & 0b10000000:
              break
      return num
  ```
- Instead of spelling out both `0b01111111` and `0b10000000` I recommend to spell just one, and make second its negation. I *may* recommend using familiar `0x7f` and `0x80` hex masks instead (but this is a matter of taste).

Comment: The class is made a singleton by a decorator, and _parse _build method signatures must match rest of the code. Reimplementing _parse looked interesting but it is wrong. Least significant bytes are first in the stream, while your code assumes otherwise. VarInt is little-endian in some sense.